# Finding the numbers of length between(8 to 16) in the Data frame of URL’s in python

Tags: python, url, numbers, partition

I am trying to find the numbers in the Data frame of URL’s which are 8 to 16 digits in length. There are 1000’s of URL's and there is no pattern. The number sometimes appears in between sometimes at the end. The only pattern I see is the there is always an "=" before the number. I want to save the the extracted results to a Column in DF.

I tried the below, they work for some URL's but not all. Please help

Example- 1 (Works)

```
url="http://www.dx.com/cgi-bin/tracking?action=track&language=english&ascend_header=1&cntry_code=us&initial=x&mps=y&tracknumbers=9261297937924338299022"

url.partition("&tracknumbers=")[2]
```

Result- `9261297937924338299022`

Example-2 (Failed)

```
url= "http://www.dx.com/track/?trknbr=279076160403&utm_source=email&utm_medium=flow-email&utm_campaign=Email%20%231%20%28UbXvKS%29&_kx=t2f6aIumzJbeNUfOHnSk_hHhn4e7OS4SAoAiz2KwVYg%3D.Nv6kNb"

url.partition("?trknbr=")[2]
```

Result- `279076160403&utm_source=email&utm_medium=flow-email&utm_campaign=Email%20%231%20%28UbXvKS%29&_kx=t2f6aIumzJbeNUfOHnSk_hHhn4e7OS4SAoAiz2KwVYg%3D.Nv6kNb`

I want to get only the number.

Comment: Use a regular expression: `\b\d{8,16}\b`

Comment: Or use `urllib` to parse the URL. It has a function to split the query string into separate key=value parts, then you can extract the key you want.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import re

PATTERN = re.compile(r"\w*=(\d{8,16})")

def find_numbers(url):
    return PATTERN.findall(url)

# update your dataframe 
df["values"] = df["URL"].map(lambda x: find_numbers(x))
```

Comment: Thank you! This works when I consider individual URL's. How do I assign the values to a DF?

Comment: num=[]
PATTERN = re.compile(r'\w*=(\d{12,22})')

def find_numbers(URL):
    return PATTERN.findall(URL)
num.append(PATTERN.findall(URL))  Type Error- expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: Are your urls stored as a DF column ?
Provide info please.

Comment: @Krishiv You didn't explain what is URL ?
How do you call `find_numbers()` ? The function is designed to operate on a string. I suspect you gave a list. Need information.

Comment: Yes, the URL’s are stored as a DF column.

Comment: @Krishiv Edited the answer to also update the dataframe with a new column named `values`. Upvote the answer if it answers the question.

Comment: PATTERN = re.compile(r"\w*=(\d{8,16})")

def find_numbers(URL):
    return PATTERN.findall(URL)

# update your dataframe 
pdf["Values"] = (pdf["URL"].map(lambda x: find_numbers(x)))
#verifying
print(pdf.Values[56])
#Returns no values when I print all
print(pdf.Values)

Comment: You've already got an answer that works here for the url parsing.
Please ask another question with your DF issue and provide all your code.